# Converting Quanteda dfm to stm

Tags: r, corpus, quanteda

I convert a tm corpus into a quanteda corpus. I apply dfm. Then I convert the dfm into stm format. This code was working just fine till 15 minutes ago; all I did was add some more words to be removed into a custom list (myRMlist). I'm baffled. Any suggestions?

```
data(tmCorpus, package = "tm") 
Qcorpus <- corpus(tmCorpus)
summary(Qcorpus, showmeta=TRUE)

myRMlist <- readLines("myremovelist2.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
Qcorpus.dfm <- dfm(Qcorpus, remove = myRMlist ) 
Qcorpus.dfm <- dfm(Qcorpus.dfm, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE, remove = stopwords("en"), stem = FALSE)
Qcorpus.dfm <- dfm(Qcorpus.dfm, remove = stopwords(("es")))
Qcorpus.stm <- convert(Qcorpus.dfm, to = "stm")

Error in convert(Qcorpus.dfm, to = "stm") : unused argument (to = "stm")
```

Comment: More information: I tested the code (without the custom remove list) on sample dataset "crude", and also using the example in the help file for wrappers for dfm convert (https://quanteda.io/reference/convert-wrappers.html?q=convert%20dfm). I get the same error. Forgot to add: Using R(3.6.3, 64bit), RStudio(1.2.5042) and Quanteda(2.0.1). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to reproduce your error since I don't have all of the inputs, but I tried recreating a set of custom words to remove, and it all worked for me.

But there are better ways to do what you are trying to do, which I list here.

**First, for me, the conversion worked.**  But there are better ways to get there: first, create the tokens object, with your word list removals, then construct the dfm.  And then, convert to the **stm** format.

```r
library("quanteda", warn.conflicts = FALSE)
## Package version: 2.0.2
## Parallel computing: 2 of 8 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

# set up data
data(crude, package = "tm")
Qcorpus <- corpus(crude)
# simulate words to remove, not supplied
myRMlist <- readLines(textConnection(c("and", "or", "but", "of")))

# conversion works
stm_input_stm <- Qcorpus %>%
  tokens(remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = c(myRMlist, stopwords("en"))) %>%
  dfm() %>%
  convert(to = "stm")
```

**However there is no need to convert** with **stm**, since `stm::stm()` can take a dfm as input directly:

```r
# stm can take a dfm directly
stm_input_dfm <- Qcorpus %>%
  tokens(remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = c(myRMlist, stopwords("en"))) %>%
  dfm()

library("stm")
## stm v1.3.5 successfully loaded. See ?stm for help. 
##  Papers, resources, and other materials at structuraltopicmodel.com

stm(stm_input_dfm, K = 5)
## Beginning Spectral Initialization 
##   Calculating the gram matrix...
##   Finding anchor words...
##      .....
##   Recovering initialization...
##      .........
## Initialization complete.
## ....................
## Completed E-Step (0 seconds). 
## Completed M-Step. 
## Completing Iteration 1 (approx. per word bound = -6.022) 
## ....................
## Completed E-Step (0 seconds). 
## Completed M-Step. 
## Completing Iteration 2 (approx. per word bound = -5.480, relative change = 9.000e-02) 
## ....................
## Completed E-Step (0 seconds). 
## Completed M-Step. 
## Completing Iteration 3 (approx. per word bound = -5.386, relative change = 1.708e-02) 
## ....................
## Completed E-Step (0 seconds). 
## Completed M-Step. 
## Completing Iteration 4 (approx. per word bound = -5.370, relative change = 2.987e-03) 
## ....................
## Completed E-Step (0 seconds). 
## Completed M-Step. 
## Completing Iteration 5 (approx. per word bound = -5.367, relative change = 6.841e-04) 
## Topic 1: said, mln, oil, last, billion 
##  Topic 2: oil, dlrs, said, crude, price 
##  Topic 3: oil, said, power, ship, crude 
##  Topic 4: oil, opec, said, prices, market 
##  Topic 5: oil, said, one, futures, mln 
## ....................
## Completed E-Step (0 seconds). 
## Completed M-Step. 
## Completing Iteration 6 (approx. per word bound = -5.366, relative change = 1.601e-04) 
## ....................
## Completed E-Step (0 seconds). 
## Completed M-Step. 
## Completing Iteration 7 (approx. per word bound = -5.366, relative change = 5.444e-05) 
## ....................
## Completed E-Step (0 seconds). 
## Completed M-Step. 
## Completing Iteration 8 (approx. per word bound = -5.365, relative change = 1.856e-05) 
## ....................
## Completed E-Step (0 seconds). 
## Completed M-Step. 
## Model Converged
## A topic model with 5 topics, 20 documents and a 971 word dictionary.
```